# load data from server only once using JQGrid and then use client side pagination,sorting etc

Tags: jqgrid

I have load data using JQGrid with parameter's datatype:'json',loadonce:true. But pagination getting disabled. I need to load data from server only one time and after that want to apply client side pagination and all.

Comment: It would help to post your entire jqgrid config

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you need to load data from server using datatype : json. you can work on the below code and set the parameters as you require. Below code will be used to reload data from server side and show specific page. Also you can refer the following link for further information [jqgrid trigger event](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods)

```
$("#mygrid").setGridParam({datatype:json}).trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:1}]);
```